# Coffeebeans gem not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, coffeescript

So here's my controller:

```
  class ScriptController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :js
    def show
      puts 'here'
      @client_id = params[:id]
      respond_with @client_id
    end
  end
```

I have a file called in `app/views/script/show.js.coffee` but it doesn't load when I go to the show page. I'm using the coffeebeans gem: [Loading .coffee files via a view in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824526/loading-coffee-files-via-a-view-in-rails)

Any help?

**EDIT: Added Error**

Template is missing

Missing template good_comments/script/show, good_comments/application/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/shamoon/Sites/good_comments/spec/dummy/app/views" * "/Users/shamoon/Sites/good_comments/app/views"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use CoffeeBeans, `coffee-rails` handles rendering of coffeescript out-of-box.

I render coffeescripts like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to '/' }
  format.js { render 'delete', :layout => false }
end
```

Comment: What is your environment? Rails version? Did you moved `coffee-rails` out of `assets` group in Gemfile?

Comment: Rails 3.1.3. I'm not sure I understand about `assets`. I'm creating an engine, so I'm doing `s.add_dependency "coffee-rails"` in my `gemspec` file

Comment: Rails uses `coffee-rails`, `therubyracer` and `execjs` to compile coffeescripts in your project. By default, `coffee-rails` present in `assets` group in Gemfile to be invoked on `rake assets:precompile`, but you can move it to your development dependencies and compile coffeescripts on the fly.

Comment: An error you added just confirm it — there are no required builders and fileformats.